# How do we style custom login buttons without fb:login-button after fbml is deprecated?

Tags: facebook, fbml, deprecated

Can you help me figure this out. Are my assumptions correct here :

1. fb:login-button will be deprecated in 2012 along with all fb: tags.
2. The alternative to fb:login-button is use a html button tag (or similar) and some javascript to handle the click event which calls FB.login or FB.logout eg; http://www.fbrell.com/auth/login-button

   3) I have to manually style the above Facebook login button/div because there is no "free" way of  styling it to look like the soon-to-be-depracated fb:login-button does

I'm just starting to get into Facebook integration for my site and have discovered the pain

Thanks
Gareth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, just FBML apps are deprecated. The XFBML tags like the fb:login button that are part of the javascript sdk or social plugins aren't deprecated. So you do not need to worry about changing them.  If they were deprecated, the [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) would reflect that.

Comment: I +1'd this answer, but here's my caveat: In this situation, considering XFBML and FBML use the same (or nearly the same syntax), they could certainly be clearer about what's getting deprecated and what's not. The docs are often updated after the fact, and counting on them as the authoritative source has left me scrambling to rewrite code before. Just a cautionary statement :)